# How do i change the console title of a python script like console.title in c#

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Is there a way to change title of a console based py program? so when i convert it to exe it'd show as "Test - v.1.5"
without using tkinter, kivy etc

Answer (score 4):

found it

```
import os
os.system("title XYZ")
```